# javascript - FileAPI - Good idea to use it for real estate WebApp?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I will explain why I do this question around Real Estate. But the explanation is complex. I will try my best.

I will build a Upload mechanism to upload photos in a Real Estate WebApp.

The Real Estate uploading of photos have some particularities. For example, it is normal a user try to upload a photo with 14MB, 16MB or even 24MB, multiply that for about 20 images and for each Real Estate Ad we can possibly have 20 * 24MB = 480MB.

It is good ideia to use the FileAPI knowing this(above)? (The uploaded files with the FileAPI go to the memory or to the disk?)

Crop, Rotate and Resize is the next subject. With the FileAPI I will be able to to this in the browser and this is what get me excited about the FileAPI. It will be easier to implement these features using the FileAPI VS do it in the server side?

Another point. The FileAPI is safe to use with multiple browsers at this time? The WebApp must be compatible across all main browsers including mobile browsers.

Some clues about "it is a good idea to use the FileAPI in 2016 with these requirements"?

Best Regards,
André

Comment: Is StackOverflow against these type of questions. When I ask for something that is not very technical but more design related, the question is not very welcome. There are other Stacks where this types of questions are welcome or should I ask it in other place? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) says the File API has decent support across different browsers.

Files get read from disk and stored in memory as binary data so that the code can interact with the contents. A 20MB file loaded into memory is probably not be an issue in terms of memory used, but around 500MB is a lot of space to take up in memory if you want to support computers without all that much memory.